# For acute triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ and circumradius $R$, define $x$, $y$, $z$ with $a+x=b+y=c+z=2R$. Show $x+y+z\lt2R$.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

This problem has been revealed to me not so easy as I would have thought.

> Let $a,b,c$ be the sides of an acute triangle and $R$ its circumradius. It is clear that there are three positive numbers $x,y,z$ such that $a+x=b+y=c+z=2R$.
>
> Prove  that $x+y+z\lt2R$.

Comment: @Blue: Thanks you very much for the better title.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to proving that $a+b+c < 4R$, which is probably more approachable.

Comment: @Greg Martin: yes but "greater than" instead of "less than" (obviously a simple lapse or typo of your part).

Comment: No, less than: since $(a+b+c)+(x+y+z) = a+x+b+y+c+z=2R+2R+2R=6R$, the inequalities $x+y+z>2R$ and $a+b+c<4R$ are equivalent.

Comment: Prove with an equilateral triangle for which $a+b+c\gt5R$. I am the one who made the mistake in the statement. I edit this one immediately. Greetings.